# Getting 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function' while using datatable in custom wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datatables

I am using a datatable to load items from database in a custom wordpress plugin. But I keep getting this error 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function'.
This is a common question but all the solutions are same and I have checked them all. The jquery and datatable libraries are loaded in correct order, no mistake in the library links and none of them loaded twice. what can be any other cause for this error??
Below is how the libraries enqueued:

```
if (!function_exists('current_actives_mng_enqueue'))
{
    function current_actives_mng_enqueue()
    {
        // JS
        wp_register_script('cur_act_mng_jquery', '//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js');
        wp_register_script('cur_act_mng_bootstrap_js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        wp_register_script('cur_act_mng_bootstrap_popper_js', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('cur_act_mng_datatable_js','//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',array('jquery'));

        wp_enqueue_script('cur_act_mng_jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('cur_act_mng_bootstrap_js');
        wp_enqueue_script('cur_act_mng_bootstrap_popper_js');
        wp_enqueue_script('cur_act_mng_datatable_js');

        // CSS
        wp_register_style('cur_act_mng_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        wp_register_style('cur_act_mng_datatable_css', '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css');
        wp_register_style('cur_act_mng_custom', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__));

        wp_enqueue_style('cur_act_mng_bootstrap');
        wp_enqueue_style('cur_act_mng_datatable_css');
        wp_enqueue_style('cur_act_mng_custom');
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'current_actives_mng_enqueue');
}
```

This is the js code for loading the table:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#cur_act_tbl').dataTable({    
        ajax: {
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=datatables_endpoint",
            cache:false,
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'mls' },        
            { data: 'status' },        
        ],
        pageLength: 25
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `$` with `jQuery` might help

```
jQuery('#cur_act_tbl').dataTable(
```

Comment: replaced as jQuery('#cur_act_tbl').dataTable(  ......but no change, same error message

Comment: It seems to me that jQuery is loaded twice `cur_act_mng_jquery` and `jquery` as a dependancy of `cur_act_mng_datatable_js`

Comment: no one is jquery and the other datatable. 'cur_act_mng_jquery' is for loading jquery (//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js) and 'cur_act_mng_datatable_js' is for loading datatable library (//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)

Comment: But if you add `jquery` as a dependancy it will enqueue jQuery again

Comment: Try removing `cur_act_mng_jquery`

Comment: It worked by removing 'cur_act_mng_jquery'. thank you! Also the bootstrap js had to be removed as the version was not compatible with datatable js